# I want to be able to terminate the program from user input

Tags: java

```
public class MyFirstApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        int beerNum = 99;
        String word = "bottles";

        while (beerNum > 0) {

            if (beerNum == 1) {
                word = "bottle";
            }

            System.out.println(beerNum + "" + word + "of beer on the wall");
            System.out.println(beerNum + "" + word + "of beer");
            System.out.println("take one down");
            System.out.println("Pass it around");
            beerNum = beerNum - 1;

            Thread.sleep(5000);

            if (beerNum > 0) {
                System.out.println(beerNum + "" + word + "of beer on the wall");
            } else {
                System.out.println("No more bottles of beer on the wall");
            }
            }

        }
    }
```

So this is just a tutorial i am going through, but i need a question answer i cant find it. I want to be able to type "s" or "stop"(It doesn't really matter which) to stop or terminate the program. While it is running the project.

Comment: I do not want to be obnoxious or anything like that but why do not you do that?!!!

Comment: I don't think you can do that in a console application.

Comment: How would i add that to an if statement in the code?

Answer (score 2):

If you're running it on the console and you want it to stop singing at you, you can type ctrl-c to kill the application.

Otherwise, you'll need to implement another thread that waits for you to type "stop" and that thread can terminate the program. It's not really something that fits with this learning example.

Comment: Nice Keyboard Interrupt. :) However, you don't need another thread. The way the program is designed, it doesn't look like you can type anything. It just doesn't seem appropriate at all. If you were to collect input, you could do it within the loop on the main thread. Otherwise, +1

Comment: Looking at the example again, you could always check for input while the Thread is sleeping for 5000ms: check for input and exit ; or sleep 1000s x5.

Comment: Desperation adds speed --- at about 30 bottles left on the wall, I bet you could type 'stop' very quickly indeed.  :)

Comment: Well, I guess you could. But by then, someone would probably not even bother and get task manager up and running! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this, I think it should work

```
Sting s = textField.getText().toString();
if("stop".equals(s)){
   System.exit(0);
}else{
   //program continue running
}
```

Comment: `"stop".equals(s)` will be better.

Comment: @ITECH-PLANET when i put that code in i got this error "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getText() from the type TextComponent"

Comment: @hammy745. **textField** should actually be a name of a textfield in your program. e.g txtStop.getText().toString();

Comment: It is a pleasure helping

Answer (score -1):

this will scan the input and will read code to exit

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
...
//put this in a method
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String exitvar = scan.nextLine();
    if (exitvar.equals("exit")){
    System.exit(0);
    }
```

Comment: You first need to read user input in order to do this. But if you place to read user input anywhere in this code, the program will be waiting for it.

Comment: By the way, my downvote is not for not reading user input, but because waiting to read user input while at the same time you want/need to write to the console w/o even using two threads it's futile.